# How can I have code in a project that won't compile for Arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide, compile, build

I want to test the algorithms in my code without needing to send it to an actual Arduino board. I figured I could lay out my project like:

```
project/
    core.cpp      # core algorithms
    core.h        # header for core.cpp
    project.ino   # Arduino setup() loop() calling into core
    pc-main.cpp   # main(argv) calling into core
```

**However, when I do this, the Arduino IDE wants to compile `pc-main.cpp`, which won't work since it uses stdio and all that. What can I do instead?**

Is there a way to hide a file from the build, other than changing the extension which would inconvenience other editors and compilers? Is there a different standard approach to this kind of problem?

---

What I've thought of:

- I could put `pc-main.cpp` in another directory and have the build for it refer to the files in the Arduino project directory, but that seems awkward and I'd like a more elegant solution.
- I could symlink the `core.*` files into the Arduino project directory from elsewhere, but that would also be inelegant, and inconvenience Windows users should one want to compile the project.
- I could put an `#ifdef` around the contents of `pc-main.cpp`, but I haven't found a suitable `#define` to check for, other than board-specific ones.

I don't want a solution which requires extra steps for each build; the whole point of trying to do this is fast and easy development.

I would also prefer one which does not bring in a whole additional build system, testing framework, or IDE; for example, I found [arduino_ci](https://github.com/ianfixes/arduino_ci) and [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/) while researching this question. I'll switch to looking at such options if there *isn't* a good solution to the problem as I've stated it here.

---

[My question is arguably the same as [Project structure to build for PC and Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/47812/project-structure-to-build-for-pc-and-arduino) at a high level, but the question and answer there are broad and about organizing modules and not how to make the build actually work.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use conditional compilation, like this:

```c++
#ifndef(ARDUINO)
// Non-Arduino code.
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there official documentation that specifies this `#define` exists?

Comment: You can add the #define to your code and manually change it when you change environments. You can look up [Arduino compiler predefined symbols](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arduino+compiler+predefined+symbols&ia=qa). Or you can tweak the IDE's compiler command to include "-DSYMBOL_OF_MY_CHOICE" which would define your symbol during an IDE compile and presumably be undefined in your desktop environment.

Comment: To be clear, I found that `ARDUINO` is already defined and I didn't need to configure anything, so Edgar's code works exactly as written. I'm asking if there's documentation for it, as I think the answer would be even better with a link.

Comment: @KevinReid: I didn't find it in a doc (although it's mentioned [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5-3rd-party-Hardware-specification#recipes-to-compile-source-code)), but [in a Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/1.6.0/Arduino.mk#L1016) intended to emulate the Arduino IDE.